# Getting an empty array in web3.eth.getAccounts()

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, next.js, solidity

i am using next.js and on sever side it web3.eth.getAccounts() is returning empty array 
so here are my to files one is index.js from pages and web3.js to get instance of web3

index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import web3 from "../ethereum/web3";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
class Index extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {
    // await window.ethereum.enable();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log(accounts);
    return { accounts };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h1>it is index page</h1>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

web3 page

```
import Web3 from "web3";

let web3;

if (typeof window !== "undefined" && typeof window.web3 !== "undefined") {
  web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
} else {
  const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/my_key"
  );
  web3 = new Web3(provider);
}

export default web3;
```

Comment: is this the exact url you are using? `"https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/my_key"` ?

Comment: @azium i hide by project key

Answer (score 1):

It's correct because there is no account in the Infura fullnode.
You should use `truffle-hdwallet-provider` instead of `web3 Prodiver`.

Comment: it works when i try this on other function but doesn't work with getInitialProps()